# Using nextjs dynamic import on multi export

Tags: next.js, next.js13

Im trying to import some components from an library but I'm strugeling with components that have multi export. Because they are both needed when rendering. I have tried flipping the imports to se if order matterd, but no.

```
'use client'
import { Select,SelectItem } from '@nextui-org/select'; // Works
// Dont work 
const Select = dynamic(() => import('@nextui-org/select').then((x) => x.Select),);
const SelectItem = dynamic(() => import('@nextui-org/select').then((x) => x.SelectItem));
```

I have another smillar example where I wrap a component with a tooltip, but because the tooltip is pulled to the client first it can't attach to the button. Is there a way to "wait" on a component to be loaded before the other?

```
'use client' 
const Button = dynamic(() => import('@nextui-org/button').then((x) => x.Button));
const Tooltip = dynamic(() => import('@nextui-org/tooltip').then((x) => x.Tooltip));
```

Comment: I think conditionally rendering second(tooltip) lazy loaded component is the only answer. Have you tried it?

Comment: Sry for late reply. I had not, but I did it now. But unfortunately the tooltip still gives the noElement to ref error. Even though I did "if (Button)".